# How to pass key value as parameter in post method

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

For Example,If I am using $scope.details in post:

```
$scope.p_id = 13;  
$scope.o_id = 1;  
 $scope.details = {
          quantity: '1',
          option: {
            p_id: o_id
          }
        };
```

I am getting the post params as { p_id: 1 }, but I want the post params as {13: 1}.
If I pass the value as

```
option: {
        [p_id]: o_id
      }
```

Now I get the params as my wish.In browser, it works fine but mobile device shows the error as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ["
Suggest an alternative solution to pass key value.

Comment: Did you try to use $scope.p_id instead of p_id ?

Comment: I was not able to use $scope.p_id inside the option.It shows error.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the error?

Comment: Getting this error " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ " on
option: {
        [p_id]: o_id
      }

Answer (score 0):

Try either of these formats:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.p_id = 13;
  $scope.o_id = 1;
  $scope.details = {};
  $scope.details.quantity = '1';
  $scope.details.option = {};
  $scope.details.option[$scope.p_id] = $scope.o_id;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>p_id: {{p_id}}</div>
    <div>o_id: {{o_id}}</div>
    <div>option: {{details.option}}</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
$scope.p_id = 13;  
$scope.o_id = 1;  
$scope.details = {};
$scope.details.quantity = '1';
$scope.details.option = {};
$scope.details.option[$scope.p_id] = $scope.o_id;
```

OR

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.p_id = 13;
  $scope.o_id = 1;
  $scope.details = {
    quantity: '1',
    option: {
      [$scope.p_id]: $scope.o_id
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>p_id: {{p_id}}</div>
    <div>o_id: {{o_id}}</div>
    <div>option: {{details.option}}</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
$scope.p_id = 13;  
$scope.o_id = 1;  
$scope.details = {
  quantity: '1',
  option: {
    [$scope.p_id]: $scope.o_id
  }
};
```

And with both:

```
$scope.result;

$scope.post = function (details){
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: //Something,
    data: {
      details: details
    };
  });
};

$scope.execute = function () {
  $scope.post($scope.details).then(function success(response){
    $scope.result = response.data;
  });
}
```

I've been told that the top one is friendlier towards mobile devices because of it being more reliable after the compression of Javascript code.

Comment: I have tried with the second option.It works well in browser but it shows error in mobile device as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ["  on this line "[$scope.p_id]: $scope.o_id".I have mentioned it already.
I would like to mention that I am using these values in post method, so the first option is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with passing data with below option.It worked.

```
        $scope.p_id = 13;  
        $scope.o_id = 1;          
        var key = [p_id];
        var option = {};
        var details = {};
        details['quantity'] = '1';
        var ids = details.option={};
        ids[key] = o_id;
```

You can pass 'details' in the post method, it works fine in both browser and mobile device.